# Missing domain http://./wp-… in redirects

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, domain

I am migrating my WP website from staging to production and I have a problem with Dashboard access.

When I try to access

```
http://<domain>/wp-admin.php
```

it redirects me to

```
http://./wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F<domain>%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

I can login with going directly to `http://<domain>/wp-login.php` and I can go to any Dashboard page but cannot change anything (with *Save* button) without redirecting to `http://./wp-admin/…`.

For example, if I want to change post content,

1. I do it and hit *Save* button.
2. Then I redirects to `http://./wp-admin/post.php?post=20&action=edit&message=1`.
3. Then I go back and see that post changes are saved.

The same problem is with changing Permalinks settings.

**So what is broken**: there is a dot `.` instead of my domain in redirect URIs.

Maybe it is because of cyrillic `одиссейдом.рф` domain?

Have I add some rewrite rules to fix it?

---

UPD:

I saved a page, go back, save again and there is no problem.

Then I tried to change site title in Settings/General and there is no problem too.

Then I tried to turn off Emoticons in Settings/Writing and there is no problem.

But activating/deactivating a plugin goes with problem.

I have no idea, my friends.

Comment: How do you migrating your website? I use this plugin and it works without problems at all. https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: I migrated with WP Migrate DB https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:
* go to permalinks under settings and check URL structure with your desired domain name. Even if the URL seems to be right, click the desired structure and save. This was handy while i migrated 2 websites.
or
* look for "wp_options" table in your database. You will find "*siteurl*" & "*baseurl*" row. Check if they are the right one.

Optional:
search the whole database for the right URL.

Comment: I checked my DB twice before creating this question and twice again now and `home` and `siteurl` is ok but `baseurl` was just missing. So I just added `baseurl` with my domain and it's work! Thank you!

Comment: one more time, it helped me just once. I still have this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to:

1. Go to */wp-admin/options-general.php* and see if your site urls are
   correct. If it works change them or edit them in the database
   manually;
2. Delete your .htaccess file or replace it with a default one;
3. You can also add the following lines of code to the
   wp-config.php file:

   Define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-site-url.com');

   Define('WP_HOME','http://your-site-url.com');

Comment: I migrated from staging with [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) and obviously I have a right WP URL.

Comment: I tried to delete `.htaccess` and it does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access :

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
```

If you can try to change the option and reselect the same one and save

Comment: Many times error like this are only related to the "permalinks"

I had the same "issues" with Polylang (multilingual plugin) but it's because it's creating permalinks too and until you do no "resave" those information (even though you see your new URL) it's like the information is not properly saved.

Ohhhh and of course if you have any plugins that creates special permalinks for your website, I suggest to go ahead and do the same thing, "re-save" those options to make sure they have the proper information)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for me even admin as not loading, My db had correct site url and home.

The solution which worked for me is, adding following lines in wp-config:

```
define('WP_HOME', YOUR_SITE_URL);
define('WP_SITEURL', YOUR_SITE_URL);
```